# gulp uglify Mangle option breaks file with non-ascii names

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, gulp, gulp-uglify

I work on UI, I'm using gulp-uglify v2.0 with an AngularJS 1.x project and it works great IF I pass the option to turn OFF mangle. Here's my exact task:

```
gulp.task('build:js', function() {
    var concat = require('gulp-concat');
    var uglify = require('gulp-uglify');
    return gulp.src(config.js.src)
        .pipe(concat(config.js.concat))
        .pipe(uglify({mangle:false})) // absence of this option is causing invalid characters        .pipe(gulp.dest(config.js.dest))
});
```

If I remove {mangle:false} the task still runs without throwing any errors. But when I try to load pages in the chrome browser that use the javascript file, it does not work. Weirdly, there are also no errors in the Output console.

Any ideas about the console not showing any errors?

Comment: Maybe the new names don't match the data that arrives from the backend?  I mean if you consume a backend service that sends a JSON object with a `username` property for instance, but mangling renamed that property to `a`, things may not work

Comment: Try `gulp-util` for logging errors while uglifying the `js` files. This would give you an idea of where the code is behaving abruptly. If you face any trouble with `gulp-util` then let me know, I will post a sample code.

Comment: Thanks Mini Bhati do you know any documentation about using gulp-util